# Why if I create a varchar(65535), I get a mediumtext?

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

Does a mediumtext and a varchar(65535) are the same thing ?
 What I mean here is do they both store the data directly in the table or do the mediumtext type is storing a pointer ?
I'm asking this because if I try to create a varchar(65535) it is automatically transform into a mediumtext (if the length is bigger than 21811 actually).

---

I've got another related question which is:

I've got some fields in a table that I want to be able to store a lot of characters (around 10'000). But in reality, it will almost all the time store no more than 10 characters.

So my question is, do I need to use a text or a varchar(10000) type for best performance ?

I believe a varchar type is more appropriate for this case.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

### Edit

The thing I don't understand is why they say that since mysql 5.0.3, we can create a varchar(65535) but when we try to do this, it convert it to a mediumtext. For me the difference between varchar and text (mediumtext include) is the way how they are store (using a pointer or not). 
So why do they say that we can create varchar with a length of 65535 if we can't?

Comment: google? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm answering to my own question:

That's because I'm using a multi-byte character. If you use an utf-8 collation, you will not be able to create a varchar with about more than 21000 chars. But if you use ascii, you will.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense, divide row limit in bytes by three. Thanks. (Just make sure your UTF-8 string only contains UCS-2 characters ;-)  ...Wow, MySQL 5.5 onwards already considers that too, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: Notice one detail: the 65535 limit is not only the Varchar limit. It's the limit of the size of the whole record. This mean if you have only one Varchar in the table, you can go up to (65535-3)/3 = 21844 char. But in reality you will not be able to go up to 21844 as other fields also use part of the 65535 bytes available.

Answer (score 7):

According to mysql.com the length of mediumtext is L + 3 bytes. To me this means that if you have an empty field it will be 3 bytes. If you have an empty varchar the length of this field will be 1 byte.

**[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html)** is clearly mentioned

> Prior to MySQL 5.0.3, a VARCHAR column with a length specification
>   greater than 255 is converted to the smallest TEXT type that can hold
>   values of the given length. For example, VARCHAR(500) is converted to
>   TEXT, and VARCHAR(200000) is converted to MEDIUMTEXT. However, this
>   conversion affects trailing-space removal.